# Selenium - How to look for one element ID and if it doesn't exist look for the next?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a small selenium script, that goes to a website and checks some stuff and performs some steps. The issue I am having is. The "s2id_ddlHotels" ID sometimes changes. The bot will find "s2id_ddlHotels" and finish the steps. But the next run it will load this element "s2id_ddlHotelsWithDate". It's only between these two elements so far I've seen. How can I handle this? Sort of tells the python code to look for "s2id_ddlHotels" first, if found do the other steps. and if that cannot be found, look for "s2id_ddlHotelsWithDate" and do the steps? I believe I have to use an IF statement here but I'm unsure how to properly implement it.

My current code:

```
try:
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_ddlHotels").click() #issue here
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen1_search').send_keys(hotelName)
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen1_search').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_name("fileRoomIncomeName").send_keys(fileName)
        time.sleep(2)
        element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fileupload-preview")
        driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].innerText = '{fileName}'", element)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
        #print(e)
```

Comment: Why can't you use `contains`?

Comment: I'm trying to click on a drop down menu, so don't think contains text would work right?

Comment: It should. Can you post HTML of drop-down?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fryx7wh6/3/

This is the html. Its a bit messy. But if I can find ID by just contains of "s2id_ddlHotels", it should be okay. Because there are two IDS. Sometimes "s2id_ddlHotels" and othertimes    "s2id_ddlHotelsWithDate"

Comment: Lets say if `s2id_ddlHotels` is not available you will get no element found exception then you want look for `s2id_ddlHotelsWithDate` element. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use Selenium's expected condition wait system.
This allows you to safely wait for the the element with in the desired time.
It becomes even easier to manage if you start wrapping it up like I did.

Below is rudimentary example of what you are looking for. It's not perfect but enough to get you started.

```py
import os
import sys
from typing import Union

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

# We are assuming the webdriver is right next to this file
THIS_FILE = os.path.abspath(__file__)
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(THIS_FILE)
# I am on linux so no *.exe file
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'chromedriver')


# Get the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)


def get_element_by_locator(the_driver, locator: str, timeout: int = 10, by=By.ID) -> Union[None, WebElement]:
    """Explicit waits by Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits
    :param the_driver: The instantiated driver you created
    :param locator: the string locator value
    :param timeout: Default wait time before giving up
    :param by: What is the locator searching By? is it an ID, XPATH, CLASSNAME?
    :return: None if not found else the found WebElement
    """

    try:
        return WebDriverWait(the_driver, timeout).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((by, locator))
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        # We could not find the element matching matched the locator
        # By returning None we can make an educated decision about what to do next
        return None


# Notice I don't have to sleep by 5 seconds anymore.
# Selenium will search for the element for up to 5 seconds before giving up.
# In that case you are going to get None or the desired element.
# Maybe you can set it to 60 seconds and if it finds it with in 6 seconds 
# you can still safely move on. Worst case you waited 60 seconds and then got None.
hotels_button = get_element_by_locator(driver, 's2id_ddlHotels', timeout=5, by=By.ID)
if hotels_button is not None:
    print('Happy times the page is in the desired state')
    hotels_button.click()
else:
    print('I did not find my element, no point in continuing')
    print('I can attempt to recover, reload the page or just quit')
    sys.exit(1)

# If you notice we only checked if the first element existed.
# Every thing below here in theory could be None also.
hotels_search_input = get_element_by_locator(driver, 's2id_autogen1_search', timeout=2, by=By.ID)
hotels_search_input.send_keys('hotelName')
hotels_search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

file_name = 'my_file'
file_name_input = get_element_by_locator(driver, 'fileRoomIncomeName', timeout=2, by=By.NAME)
file_name_input.send_keys(file_name)

file_upload_preview = get_element_by_locator(driver, "fileupload-preview", timeout=2, by=By.CLASS_NAME)
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].innerText = '{file_name}'", file_upload_preview)
```